# Kivy icon file pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am developing an application (cross-platform) on kivymd. I solved many problems and difficulties myself, but I can’t figure out how to change (install) the application icon, which is like an exe in a folder? I wrote in the code

`Config.window_icon = "data/images/favicon.ico"`

далее в bild

```
self.icon = 'data/images/favicon.ico'
```

не помогло.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDe9o.png)

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался!
В .spec файле в разделе EXE надо добавить icon='data/images/favicon.ico' и готово!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).